# Unexpected Token in jQuery Call to ASP.NET MVC4 Web API Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, jsonp

I'm calling an MVC4 Web API service that I am building just to learn MVC and Web API. I'm having an issue with my jQuery call. I keep getting an unexpected token error.

http://jsbin.com/ayuvak/1/edit

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I suspect this is very easy but I was up until 4:00 AM working on another project and cannot focus to save my life.

```
$(document).ready(
      function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://sub.robertkaucher.com/api/Subtitles/5?callback',
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "jsonp"
        });
        function callback(data) {
            $('#divContent').html(data.SubFile);

        }
      });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking your service to return JSONP, but the service is returning JSON as content-type. Thats why you are getting this error. Can you try making the response header to return content-type to  text/javascript instead of application/json ?

Also a better way to fix cross origin policy is to use [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing). [This](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2012/07/02/cors-support-in-asp-net-web-api-rc-version.aspx) is a great post explaining how to enable CORS support in Web API